# How to select a column inserted using trigger?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I created the following tables:

```
create table people (
        ID              varchar2(9),
        name            varchar2(20),
        CONSTRAINT pk_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

 create table cars (
        license_plate   varchar2(9),
        ID              varchar2(9),
        CONSTRAINT pk_license_plate PRIMARY KEY (license_plate)
);

create table accidents (
        code          varchar2(9),
        license_plate varchar2(9),    
        CONSTRAINT pk_code PRIMARY KEY (code)
);
```

I inserted the following data:

```
insert into people(ID, name) values('0x1','Louis');
insert into people(ID, name) values('0x2','Alice');
insert into people(ID, name) values('0x3','Peter');

insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('001','0x1');
insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('002','0x2');
insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('003','0x1');
insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('004','0x3');

insert into accidents(code, license_plate) values('fd1','001');
insert into accidents(code, license_plate) values('fd2','004');
insert into accidents(code, license_plate) values('fd3','002');
```

The question is: How to make a trigger that after adding a new car , Oracle displays a message type : " The X client has bought the car whose license plate is Y". ?

For example, i inserted the following data:

```
insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('005','0x1');
```

Oracle:

> "The client "Louis" has bought the car whose license plate is 005".

I have tried the following trigger:

```
create or replace trigger
after insert on cars
for each row
declare
    cursor c_trigger is
    select p.name, c.license_plate
    from people p, cars c
    where p.ID=c.ID
    and c.license_plate=:new.licenseplate;
v_trigger c_trigger%rowtype;
begin
open c_trigger;
dbms_output.put_line('The client' || v_trigger.name || 'has bought the car whose license plate is' || v_trigger.license_plate);
fetch c_trigger into v_trigger;
close c_trigger;
end trigger;
/
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to create that trigger? And when you tried to insert? And have you `set severoutput on` in the session before you do your insert? Not that you should rely on output being available - you shouldn't assume anyone will ever see it, as you've discovered. But if that is the assignment, you need to tell the client to show the `dbms_output` buffer. Though you won't be getting that far, your trigger seems to have some issues...

Comment: yes I have done it, thanks for the suggestion . @AlexPoole

Comment: @Python241820 Does it work after that? or do you still have the problem? in case - take a look at the docs https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#ARPLS67307

Comment: @micklesh I have a error in the line: "    and c.license_plate=:new.licenseplate;
" PLS- 00049 : variable linked ' NEW.NUMERO ' is wrong | I have to get the license_plate of the insert row but not how to do it

Comment: The code in your question doesn't refer to 'numero'...

Comment: your column is license_plate and not licenseplate as you've spelled it in the line that gives you the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trigger doesn't have a name; you're producing your output after you open the cursor but before you fetch so there is no current row; and your cursor is trying to query the table the trigger is against, which will cause a mutating-table error. You also need some whitespace in your output.

You don't need to look at the `cars` table as you have all the data you need in the `new` pseudorecord.

```
create or replace trigger cars_ai_trig
after insert on cars
for each row
declare
  cursor c_trigger is
    select p.name 
    from people p
    where p.ID = :new.ID;
  v_trigger c_trigger%rowtype;
begin
  open c_trigger;
  fetch c_trigger into v_trigger;
  dbms_output.put_line('The client ' || v_trigger.name || ' has bought the car whose license plate is ' || :new.license_plate);
  close c_trigger;
end trigger;
/

Trigger CARS_AI_TRIG compiled

set serveroutput on
insert into cars(license_plate, ID) values('005','0x1');

1 row inserted.
The client Louis has bought the car whose license plate is 005
```

You don't really need a cursor here, you could have a simple scalar variable and select directly in to that:

```
create or replace trigger cars_ai_trig
after insert on cars
for each row
declare
  v_name people.name%type;
begin
  select p.name
  into v_name
  from people p
  where p.id = :new.id;

  dbms_output.put_line('The client ' || v_name || ' has bought the car whose license plate is ' || :new.license_plate);
end trigger;
/
```

I'd also consider changing the column name 'ID' to something more descriptive; in the `cars` table it isn't obvious that it's a person ID. You should also probably have a foreign key constraint on that, and on `accidents.license_plate`. Without that FK relationship you can insert an ID into `cars` which doesn't exist in `people`; and in that case the trigger will get a no-data-found exception.